# Laravel Console Command Failing to Complete Execution

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the script below which is used to send messages (sms, email & whatsapp) to some 300k customers. Things where working fine before but for some days now the script is bugging (it freezes at some point in the loop. I can see this with the progress bar which doesn't move further). I have checked `laravel.log` and there is no particular error message. The script itself does not output any error message.

Below is the code:

```
/**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        AccountsCstm::where('authentification_c', 1)->chunk(10000, function ($customer_details) {

            $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($customer_details));

            $bar->start();

            foreach ($customer_details as $customer_detail) {
                // Get customer bills and send through the appropriate channel. He could have multiple bills
             if (isset($customer_detail->account->sic_code)) {

                $bills = TbBillsInfos::where('contract_number', $customer_detail->account->sic_code)->where('bill_status', 'UNPAID')->get();
                if (isset($bills)){
                    foreach ($bills as $bill) {
                        // Send messages.
                        if ($customer_detail->is_whatsapp_c) {

                            $message = $this->bill_message($customer_detail, $bill, 'WhatsApp');
                            // Send the message
                            $this->send_whatsapp_message($customer_detail->phone_4_c, $message, $customer_detail->contract_number_c);
                            // Record the message in database
                            $this->save_message('WhatsApp', $customer_detail->phone_4_c, null, $message, $customer_detail->account->id);

                        } elseif ($customer_detail->is_sms_c) {

                            $message = $this->bill_message($customer_detail, $bill, 'SMS');
                            // Send the message
                            $this->send_sms($customer_detail->phone_4_c, $message);
                            // Record the message in database
                            $this->save_message('SMS', $customer_detail->phone_4_c, null, $message, $customer_detail->account->id);

                        } elseif ($customer_detail->is_mail_c) {

                            $message = $this->bill_message($customer_detail, $bill, 'Email');
                            // Send the message
                            $this->send_email($customer_detail, $bill, $message);
                            // Record the message in database
                            $this->save_message('Email', null, $customer_detail->mail_c, $message, $customer_detail->account->id);

                        }
                    }
                }

              }

                $bar->advance();
            }

            $bar->finish();
        });

        // Delete all record from the tb_bills_infos table
        // Set the auto-increment value to 0
        TbBillsInfos::truncate();

        Log::info('send:unpaid-bill-messages: Command executed successfully');
    }
```

Please can someone point out what can be the issue with the above script? Why is it bugging and not completing execution ? Why is it freezing at some point in the loop?

See for example the command since April 21, where as before it will complete execution in about 15 minutes or less

[image]

I have equally checked RAM usage on the server and only 1GB out of 8GB is being used. So the server is stable

Comment: Try it with cursor instead of chunk. Cursor essentially loads the entire query results into memory and only inflated one model every iteration. Chunk inflates the amount of models as is specified (10k in your case) and keeps them in memory then loads the next set using another query to the db. That may cause your results to be duplicated which could explain multiple emails being sent to the same user. Try that first.

Comment: Hi @Savlon, no success with cursor as well. The main problem is that the script kind of freezes around the 27,000 record in the loop. It doesn't advance. This is also the problem experience with chunck. With with progress bar implemented, I can see clearly that at some point it freezes. What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you queueing the sending of the emails/sms?? You shouldn’t be sending directly from the internals of the command, you should be queueing them and allowing your queue to do the work so it can allocate resources automatically.

Comment: I am queuing for email but for SMS & WhatsApp, I am sending on the flight via API calls

Comment: Ah ok. Are you able to put them into a job each and add them to the queue to test if either of those are the issue instead of sending during the execution of the function.

Comment: Hi @Savlon, I think I can see where the problem is coming. I disable the line for sending sms and the script has executed successfully. I will try to put the function in a job and see what happens. Can you share a link on how to put this API call in a queue job? I am using curl for both sms and WhatsApp calls

Comment: Just create a job and put the sending code inside of the job. Then replace the original call with dispatch the job onto the queue. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues

Comment: Hi @Savlon, using a job solve the issue. the script no longer hands. However, there is another challenge. I have 30,000 sms in the database. queue:work is taking forever to process these SMS. Testing manually, queue:work stop after sending like 30 sms. then I have to run queue:work again, it will process another 7 or so and then I get the message "process stop" again. How do I fix this ?

Comment: What is the progress saying? You also aren’t returning a status code from the handle function of your command. Check the queue log and see what that says. Are you running the queue using supervisor?

Comment: I am running the queue using supervisor. I am sending sms using an API with curl. When you exécuté queue: work on the terminal, it will be sending the sms and at a certain point it stops with a message "process stop"

Comment: I think it can be a timeout issue

Comment: Ah yeh try increasing the timeout and see if that helps. You could also implement a timer to log the time for each execution to gauge the jobs which are expensive

Comment: Hi @Savlon, I have increased timeout to 60s but still the queue:work process will just stop after the 60s timeout after sending like 8 sms.

Comment: Increase more like 24hrs in seconds